# Chaning pitch in a raw audio file?

Tags: java, android, audio, wav

Say you have a raw audio file in java/android and need to change its pitch, for example, to make a voice low as Darth Vader or something... what do you think would be the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This looks like one way to accomplish you want to do **if you want to do this client side** :

http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/

have you also considered doing it server side, so that you're not restricted to just Java/Android? there will be more sound processing libraries

Comment: Thanks, looks promising!

Comment: np, i haven't used it personally, but good luck!!